# Automatically enabled caching in some hosting companies w/o visible plugin (Must use plugin)

Tags: cache

Suddenly WP customizer can't show the Lve color change w/o actually saving and then going back to the live website.

Please see this image there is no third party cache plugin activated:

[image]

Caching on the live website also:

[image]

## Update

Default WP theme set with all plugins disabled. still, this setting coming.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not showing up in any of mine, so probably not. Disable plugins one by one, and check your theme -  it's not only plugins that can manipulate the admin bar.

Comment: is your WordPress updated to the latest version?

Comment: Yes, 4.9.2. Also, look at the Caching menu's source, the ID/class sometimes gives some hint at what plugin is adding it.

Comment: Can Hostgator throw some default caching?

Comment: Everything is possible, but I doubt that any hosting provider injects code into your WP system. I've never used them, though. Does "Caching" have any sub items? What URL does it link to?

Comment: Oh, seems I was wrong ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574915/wordpress-endurance-cache

Comment: Bluehost uses this as well.

Comment: @Milo that means they are injecting such plugins?

Comment: Are you on a managed wordpress hosting? most managed hosting have their own caching enabled.

Comment: Maybe some kind of [Must Use Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins).

Comment: @Milo, Your suggestion helped me to get rid of the issue. If you have some time can you convert your advice into an answer?